# how to take inputs as an equality in shell script (bash)

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on my project and it requires a shellscript that will rename all the files 
in a directory.The first argument is a base
name, second argument is a file extension. If it is run as:

```
./myprog4.sh BASE=Birthday EXT=jpg
```

then the resulting files should have names like:
`Birthday001.jpg`, `Birthday002.jpg`, `Birthday003.jpg`, etc.

But I couldn't take the inputs as an equality like `BASE=$1`.
Normally when I take the inputs while executing the script file I write something like:

```
base=$1 
extension=$2
```

What should I do?

Comment: why not just call the function as `./myprog4.sh Birthday jpg` ?

Comment: thats what i'm wondering actually too. but its given project as a homework thats why i have to do it in this way :S don't you have any idea?

Comment: Are you required to use this particular format? Normally, you can use [getopts](https://rsalveti.wordpress.com/2007/04/03/bash-parsing-arguments-with-getopts/) which takes a single letter parameter. So you can do `myprog.sh -b Birthday -e jpg`. Could the input be `myprog.sh EXT=jpg BASE=Birthday`? That would make things trickier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's similar how you read `$1` and `$2` into variables but extract only the necessary parts:

```
base=$(echo $1 | cut -d'=' -f2)
extension=$(echo $2 | cut -d'=' -f2)
```

In bash, you can also do:

```
base=$(cut -d'=' -f2 <<<$1)
extension=$(cut -d'=' -f2 <<<$2)
```

Comment: What if `myprog EXT=jpg BASE=Birthday`?

Comment: @DavidW. Then you have switch $1 & $2 or if the inputs are in randon order then use a case statement and match EXT= and BASE=.

Comment: @Blue Moon i should have checked that one too .i will check that as you explained.I will write a switch statement for that problem. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1):

First, know that you can set values in the environment of your program by *prefixing* the command with the variable assignments:

```
BASE=Birthday EXT=jpg ./myprog4.sh
```

When `myprog4.sh` starts, it will see `BASE` and `EXT` with the given values. After `myprog4.sh` exists, `BASE` and `EXT` retain their old values (or remain unset, as the case may be).

---

`bash` does allow you to call your program the way you are trying, with the `-k` option. From the man page:

> **-k**      All arguments in the form of assignment statements are placed in the environment for a command, not just those  that  precede the command name.

To use it, you would need to use the `set` command to enable this option before you call `myprog4.sh`.

```
$ set -k
$ ./myprog4.sh BASE=Birthday EXT=jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your arguments are passed in form of `name=value`, then you can do do the following in the beginning of your myprog4.sh script.

```
while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
   expr $1
  shift
done
```

When you call `./myprog4.sh BASE=Birthday EXT=jpg` your script will be able to do echo $BASE and echo $EXT.